Combining rotations
Is there a way to get this rotation in 3D space with math (I assume with matrices)?
Gif of said rotation

No need for rotation matrices, this is just a parametric curve to a torus:
$$\mathbf r(\Phi,\theta(\Phi))=((a+b\cos(\theta))\cos\Phi,(a+b\cos(\theta))\sin\Phi,b\sin\theta),\ \ \Phi\in[0,2\pi],$$
where $a$ is the radius of the general or circular trajectory, and $b$ is the radius of the helical trajectory.
Here's an example with $\theta=n\Phi$: https://www.desmos.com/3d/7mrdefetlu?lang=es

Coool! This is a very interesting problem! Note $n$ needs to be integer for the complete joining.
